# Creating button to generate SQL table to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am making a program where a user clicks on a button in windows form, it will execute a sql script and create the table to my sql server.

However, when the button is clicked, it throws a "SqlExeption was unhandled" message generating " CREATEBEGINNULL". I double checked my queries and database name and it all checks out so I am running out of idea.

Here is my code:

```
  private void btnCreateTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




            string query = "IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST','U') IS NULL";
            query += "BEGIN";
            query += "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST](";
            query += "[AuditID] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,";
            query += "[AuditType] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,";
            query += "[CardTypeBenefitID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,";

            query += "[EventCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,";
            query += "[CardTypeGroupID] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,";
            query += "[AgeFrom] [int] NULL,";
            query += "[AgeTo] [int] NULL,";

            query += "[Gender] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,";
            query += "[CreateBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,";
            query += "[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,";
            query += "[Status] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,";
            query += "[CancelReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,";
            query += "[LastChangeBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,";
            query += "[LastChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,";
            query += "[RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL";
            query += ") ON [PRIMARY]";
            query += "END";


    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;


         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {


                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();


                }
            }
```

And here is the code in app.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2;Initial Catalog=GVS2_Dev_GHR;Integrated Security=true"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This exception means you can't access the server from the computer running the software. There might be several reasons for it (using the wrong IP address, blocked by firewall, sql server is down ect'), but non of them is related in any way to whatever SQL statement you try to run.

Comment: Can you connect to the DB via SSMS from this machine?

Comment: use entity framework code first. =/

Comment: Are you sure the SQL Server remote instance is `172.28.40.19\\CASINO2008R2`? Also check firewall rules & MSSQL service availability on target machine.

Comment: You are using a trusted login, so I guess it depends who is actually running your application at the point where it tries to connect to the database.  If this was a web service for example then you might have a system account as the actual user, which would be unlikely to pass the SQL server security.  I would add a standard user/ password login, adjust your connection string to use this and retest.  At least this way you can isolate the problem?

Comment: Yes I could access to the DB via SSMS from my machine. The server remote has only one \ , that was a typo. I edited the post

Comment: Now the issue is gone but it generates a new exception : Incorrect syntax near 'NULLBEGINCREATE ' .  The error is highlighted under "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Comment: @ Richard This is not a web system, which is why I am using a trusted login on my computer.

Comment: @LordCookie Add blank space to every end of your query. Replace `";` with ` ";`

Comment: @ Rokuto I don't follow what you're trying to say.

Comment: Rokuto, it will generate incorrect syntax error.

Comment: You are concating strings e.g. `BEGIN` and `CREATE TABLE ...`. Without blank spaces you get `BEGINCREATE TABLE ...` which gives error. You have to add blank space to every string e.g. `BEGIN(blank space)` and ` CREATE TABLE ...(blank space)` and you will get `BEGIN CREATE TABLE ... (blank space)`

Comment: So if i understand correctly, I should change from "BEGIN"; to "BEGIN "; ?

Comment: Yes, excatly. And do it with every string.

Comment: Hey it works , maybe you could post it as an answer so i could marked it.

Comment: Great, I will add answer as soon as possible.

Comment: So if I want to create more than one table (say 20 tables) using this method, I could just hardcode all the sql scripts in the same method? Do I have to declare connection string to each table being created?

Comment: So based on this, if I want to create table with constraints,indexes,etc  then I could do it this way too? What if there are tables that are referenced to other tables, I have to execute them in order right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you concat this two strings

```
query += "BEGIN";
query += "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST](";
```

you will get

```
BEGINCREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST](
```

But this will generate Incorect syntax exception.
You have to add blank space to every string:

```
query += "BEGIN ";
query += "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST]( ";
```

Your code should look like below:

```
string query = "IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST','U') IS NULL ";
            query += "BEGIN ";
            query += "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST]( ";
            query += "[AuditID] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[AuditType] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[CardTypeBenefitID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL, ";

            query += "[EventCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[CardTypeGroupID] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, ";
            query += "[AgeFrom] [int] NULL, ";
            query += "[AgeTo] [int] NULL, ";

            query += "[Gender] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, ";
            query += "[CreateBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[Status] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[CancelReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[LastChangeBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[LastChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, ";
            query += "[RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL ";
            query += ") ON [PRIMARY] ";
            query += "END ";
```

If you want to create more tables on the same database you can do it without declaring or opening new connection.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
          ...
        }
```

where `query1`, `query2`, etc. are queries creating your tables.
You can also create one big query (by concating `query1`, `query2`, etc.) and execute it only once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Would this be the best possible way to create many tables using my method?

Comment: @LordCookie I am sorry, but I don't know. I am inexperienced in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the current user can connect to SQL using windows authentication mode, otherwise as you described, it will throw you that error message hence unable to connect.

Alternatively, put `user id` and `password` and connect using mixed mode authentication. Of course, you must have mixed mode enable in your SSMS and a user must be present in there.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2;Initial Catalog=GVS2_Dev_GHR;User ID=avatar;Password=avatar@123;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

For more info about SQL authentication modes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems the problem is now fixed. Look above in the comment section , it gives a new error.